# Fuzzy Rule Interpolation in Expression recognition

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the FRI toolbox to classify a facial expression. I am using LBP as the extraction algorithm. Please can someone Educate me on how to get the extracted features and work with them with the Fuzzy Rule Interpolation to classify a facial expression.

Comment: "Educate me". XD This isn't really the place for that. You should maybe start by reading the docuementation or Googleing it

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kev. But I have done many readings through the documentation. The Challenge is that I am new in machine learning, so I have been trying to know how to use the extracted features gotten from LBP algorithm to classify an emotion using the Fuzzy Rule Interpolation.